# Let $z$ and $w$ be two complex numbers satisfying $z+\bar{w}=z^2$ and $w+\bar{z}=w^2.$ Then numbers of ordered pairs $(z,w)$ is/are

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $z$ and $w$ be two complex numbers satisfying $z+\bar{w}=z^2$ and $w+\bar{z}=w^2.$

Then numbers of ordered pairs $(z,w)$ is equal to

(A) $1\quad$  (B) $2\quad$ (C) $3\quad$ (D) N.O.T

**My Approach:**

I took conjugate of $z+\bar{w}=z^2$ and obtained $\bar{z}+w=\bar{z}^2$

Now I compared $w+\bar{z}=w^2$ and $w+\bar{z}=\bar{z}^2$ and I obtained $w=\bar{z}$ and $w=-\bar{z}$.

And after substituting above value of $w$ in given equation I got following three pairs of $z$ and $w$ which are $(0,0), (2,0),(2,2)$ But answer given is $2$

**Please tell me where am I going wrong?**

Comment: You introduced $z_1$ and $z_2$ and didn't mention them again

Comment: The question is unclear as you want ORDERD PAIR! $(w,z))$ where w and z themselves complex numbers (ordered pair).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solutions are $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$. And can easily check for yourself that $(2,0)$ is *not* a solution. Why would it be? If $z=2$ and $w=0$, you *don't* have $w=\pm\overline z$.